# How do I get a date or datetime out of an SQLite3 row?

Tags: objective-c, c, datetime, date, sqlite

There is no function as `sqlite3_column_date` which I need:

```
int i = 0;
for (NSString *key in [self valuesWithTypes]) {
  id value;
  if ([[[self valuesWithTypes] objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    value = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i)] autorelease];
  }
  else if ([[[self valuesWithTypes] objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
    value = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:sqlite3_column_double(statement, i)] autorelease];
  }
  else if ([[[self valuesWithTypes] objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]) {
//  value = // WTF
  }
  else if ([[[self valuesWithTypes] objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
    value = [[NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, i) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, i)] autorelease];
  }
  [rowDictionary setValue:value forKey:key];
  i++;
}
```

SQLite3 tables can have a date/datetime typed column. But how, in the name of the holy Lord, can I get a date column out of a row?

Thanks

Comment: According to SQLite documentation ( http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html ) there is no date/datetime column. Get your datetime in number of seconds (a UNIX timestamp) and write/read that with INTEGER SQLite3 data type

Comment: @pmg `sqlite3_column_int64(statement, i)`? Unfortunately I still cannot accept a comment. >.<

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) there is no date/datetime column.

In that page three options are suggested:

- TEXT
- REAL
- INTEGER

TEXT may be the prettier option if you need to look at the data directly.
I've never used REAL
I like INTEGER and UNIX timestamps :-)

32-bits UNIX timestamps have a [problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) looming very near (no issue with 64-bits timestamps) and they don't reflect wall-clock time accurately. If a second too much or too little every now and then isn't a problem for you, I'd suggest this option.

Comment: Do you see a major issue with storing datetime as TEXT? I find the way SQLite stores passed dates to UTC very annoying. What do you think? I could open a question if you suggest me to do so. Thank you.

Comment: @NoChance: the biggest issue I can think of is efficiency/speed for encoding/decoding. If you don't mind using extra bytes on storage media and if you don't mind using a few micro-seconds more for each fetch/write/compare then TEXT is perfectly ok.